# TeamCity: The dependency Microsoft.Extensions.Options.ConfigurationExtensions >= 1.0.0 could not be resolved

Tags: visual-studio-2015, continuous-integration, teamcity, .net-core

I have a build step in my TeamCity server with the following configurations.

*NOTE: TeamCity is installed in the same machine as my development machine so when I say "TeamCity server I'm referring to my own PC"*

**Runner Type:** Visual Studio (sln)

**Step Name:** Build Solution

**Execute Step:** If all previous steps finished successfully

**Solution file path:** MySolutionFile.sln

**Targets:** Clean Rebuild

**Configuration:** Release

When **Build Solution** step is executed in TeamCity, I get the following error when one of my projects `Project.Api.Rest` is building:

`[Dnx] C:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\ccd41c6e23422588\Project.Api.Rest\project.json(16, 71): error NU1001: The dependency Microsoft.Extensions.Options.ConfigurationExtensions >= 1.0.0 could not be resolved.`

**ERROR:**

[image]

My `Project.Api.Rest` builds perfectly inside Visual Studio without a problem. Also, out of curiosity, I tried to execute the command that TeamCity is using and it also works perfectly fine, take a look at the screenshot.

**COMMAND:**

`dotnet build "C:\ProjectPath\Project.Api.Rest" --configuration Release --no-dependencies --no-incremental`

**WORKING COMMAND:**

[image]

How can I solve this TeamCity error?

**TeamCity Version: 9.1.6 (build 37459)**

**Visual Studio 2015**

**Windows 10 64-bit**

Comment: I'm facing the same problem here at the company. Do you manage to solve this?

Comment: @ElmerDantas I somehow managed to to fix this issue but it's not a complete solution. You can delete the `.lock.json` file for each project that has this error

Comment: I don't think my problem is with `lock.json` file because I do not have it in my repository. I'm still trying because I have more dependency problem than you had. if I manage to solve, I come back to tell you. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I managed to resolve something very similar to this by adding a Command Line build step first which ran dotnet restore:

**Runner Type:** `Command Line`

**Run:** `Custom Script`

**Custom Script:**

```
cd "C:\The location of your solution\"
```

dotnet restore

Then the first thing the build does is install the packages:

[Step 1/2] `log  : Installing Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ApiExplorer 1.0.1.`

This allowed my solution to build afterwards with no

> The dependency xxxx cannot be resolved

errors.